# 'Async' tests runs forever jest

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, jestjs

I have a problem on new environment with `async` tests with jest

```
    "jest": "^27.4.6",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-android-location-enabler|react-native-config|react-native-actionsheet|@sentry/react-native|reselect|redux-persist)/)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
```

the case is that event trying to run the simplest test ever, jest never actually execute it:

```
const giveMeAfterSec = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('wow');
        }, 1000);
    });
};

describe('dummy', () => {
    test('async test', async () => {
        const result = await giveMeAfterSec();

        expect(result).toBe('wow');
    });
});
```

and trying to run it, I see never ending

`RUNS src/__tests__/dummy.test.tsx`

Every test without `async await` runs properly

Comment: It works on my setup "jest": "27.2.4".

Comment: version change does nothing. 
Do you have an idea which part of the setup could cause it?

Comment: Indeed, this is weird. I've copied the exact same code from your question and run it in my setup. It worked as expected. I'm using the builtin VSCode jest extension. Are you starting jest from the command line? is your code snippet in an isolated file or are there other test cases or maybe some beforeTest statements?

Comment: @DavidScholz which testrunner do you use ?